# Gettting a field from a $request_body and compare it with specific value in a location server nginx

Tags: nginx, curl

I would like to compare a field inside a body from a POST request, using a nginx server, but can't find a way to do it:

For example:

**API request**:

```
 curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/my-post-api' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "nico",
}'
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        location /my-post-api {
            default_type 'application/json';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;

            if (<CODE HERE TO COMPARE $request_body FIELD name WITH A VALUE, FOR EXAMPLE 'nico'>) {
                  return 201 "{}";
            }
    
            return 404 "{}";

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to analyze `$request_body` using the `if` directive. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64488040/7121513) is my last year research on this subject. And even that way (I mean using the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive) it is impossible to use mapped variable in most parts of the nginx config (for example, you can't use `add_header <header_name> $mapped_variable`).

---

**Update @ 2022.05.17** The above assumption is wrong, actually you *can* use that mapped variable as a parameter of the `add_header` directive (and possibly some others too) if the [`$request_body`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_body) variable didn't get accessed during the early request processing phases (see the last update to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64488040/7121513) answer) and the used location configuration and content handler assumes the request body will be read during the request processing:

> The variable’s value is made available in locations processed by the `proxy_pass`, `fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass`, and `scgi_pass` directives when the request body was read to a memory buffer.

---

The only way I see so far (without using [lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) or [njs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/index.html) modules) is to use two `map` directives and two `server` blocks:

```
map $request_body $request_passed {
    '~"name":\s*"nico"'    1;
    default                0;
}

map $http_x_request_passed $number {
    1                      1;
    default                0;
}

server {
    listen 8081;
    default_type 'application/json';
    location / {
        try_files /dev/null @loc$number;
    }
    location @loc0 {
        return 404 "{}";
    }
    location @loc1 {
        return 201 "{}";
    }
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    location /my-post-api {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        proxy_set_header 'X-Request-Passed' $request_passed;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

This doesn't look like a very elegant solution, but at least it should work.